# IXRepository and test problems

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, architecture

Recently [had a doubt](https://twitter.com/Ridermansb/status/342750250341134336) about how and where to test repository methods.
Let the following situation: I have an interface `IRepository` like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
    where T: class, IEntity
{
    IQueryable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
    // ... Omitted
}
```

And a generic implementation of `IRepository`

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class, IEntity
{
    public IQueryable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return All().Where(expression).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

This is an implementation base that can be used by any repository. It contains the basic implementation of **my ORM**.

Some repositories have specific filters, in which case we will `IEmployeeRepository` with a specific filter:

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee>
{
    IQueryable<Employee> GetInactiveEmployees();
}
```

And the implementation of `IEmployeeRepository`:

```
public class EmployeeRepository : Repository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository // TODO: I have a dependency with ORM  at this point in Repository<Employee>. How to solve? How to test the GetInactiveEmployees method
{
    public IQueryable<Employee> GetInactiveEmployees()
    {
        return Query(p => p.Status != StatusEmployeeEnum.Active || p.StartDate < DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

### Questions

1. Is right to inherit `Repository<Employee>`?
   The goal is to reuse code once all implementing `IRepository` already been made. If `EmployeeRepository` inherit only `IEmployeeRepository`, I have to literally copy and paste the code of `Repository<T>`.
2. In our example, in `EmployeeRepository : Repository<Employee>` our `Repository` lies in our ORM layer. We have a dependency here with our ORM impossible to perform some **unit test**.
3. How to create a **unit test** to ensure that the filter `GetInactiveEmployees` return all Employees in which the Status != Active and StartDate < DateTime.Now. I can not create a Fake/Mock of `IEmployeeRepository` because I would be testing? Need to test the actual implementation of `GetInactiveEmployees`.

The complete code can [be found on Github](https://github.com/Ridermansb/GenerateIdDesignerProblem/tree/irepository-test)

Answer (score 1):

1. This strikes me as a has-a relationship, since as you mention this class is acting as a filter. So rather than inheriting it should have a private `IRepository<Employee>` field that it can receive when `EmployeeRepository` is constructed.
2. Having the option to provide an `IRepository<Employee>` would allow you to mock/fake it and separate the testing concerns.
3. Yes, you don't need to create a mock object of the thing you're testing. You just need to be able to isolate the method's behaviour by providing *ideal objects for the object you are testing to manipulate.*